# IIS is not loading .css files

Tags: iis, server

Hi I just started working with an `IIS` server for my `AngularJS` project.

So my problem is that my project loads angular, but not `.css` files, neither my own nor bootstraps.

I have looked at the big fat web, and I noticed that most solutions is to check `static content` in `Windows features`. However that was already ticked for me. And I'm wondering if there are other solutions?

[image]

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="SimPlannerApp">
    <head>
        ...

        <!-- Load Bootstrap CSS library -->
        <link type="text/css" href="lib/bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

        <!-- Load AngularJS modules -->
        <script src="lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/Angular-1.4.7/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Load AngularJS Application -->
        <script src="core.js"></script>

        <!-- Our CSS -->
        <link type="text/css" href="assets/styles/main.css">
        <link type="text/css" href="assets/styles/nav.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        ...

        <!-- This is where page content is inserted to -->
        <div ui-view></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**File tree**

- assets
- styles

  - main.css
  - nav.css
- lib
- Angular-1.4.7

  - angular.min.js
  - angular-ui-router.min.js
- bootstrap-3.3.5-dist

  - css

    - bootstrap.min.css
- index.html
- core.js

**Files loaded to the browser**

[image]

Comment: have you refered them with correct path on the page?

Comment: CSS is served by the Static Content handler. What HTTP response (including any message in the HTML) does IIS give you when you request a CSS file? Maybe you have a File Extension MIME-type entry deleted by mistake.

Comment: You say "not loading"... are you seeing any `404 Not Found`?

Comment: I get no `404 not found` error, or any error for that matter, the css files are not getting send to the browser as far as I can see

Comment: In your server, don't you have any code (it looks like MVC here). I mean is that a visual studio website project or pure static files?

Comment: In the IIS Manager, is there an entry for the `.css` extension to treat them as `text/css`?

Comment: @MacKentoch: I'm not using `Visual Studio`, for the server I'm using `IIS` and I've added my files to that and then call it in the browser as `localhost:8080/simplanner/#/route`

Comment: @JBKing: I just double checked, and `.css` is registered in my MIME-types as you suggest

Comment: @MichaelTotKorsgaard ok so it is not trick of MVC bundler that uses minified version of assets when deployed on server.

Comment: @MacKentoch: no it's not, no minified files here ^^

Answer (score 2):

A guy in my team found the solution. When referencing the stylesheets I've forgotten the `rel="stylesheet"` after each of them.

so this

```
<link type="text/css" href="assets/styles/main.css">
```

should be this

```
<link type="text/css" href="assets/styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```